# ui for a shiny app with two images on top and a table at the bottom

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a shiny app. I have two images and a table . I am trying to design my ui based on this example below

https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-biclust/

If anybody can help me with a rough outline for the ui based this example that will be helpful.

Comment: @the link you provided has a source code that can help you to get started

Answer (score 0):

That is flexhdashboard layout! You may want to read this to learn how to make a report with that layout:

http://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/using.html

Also in your example you can find the source code of the report by clicking on "Source Code" button on the top right of the report.

Comment: @TruongDuy I copy pasted a simple FlexBoard code in RStudio from this website`(http://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/using.html#layout)` and I got a lot of error. I am not sure what scripting language that is, I only know R.